# Moving Ball with pan

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm using pan gesture and after it moves I'm trying to get  it to move at the angle that the touch happen. I though to get the point of the touch when the pan happened and then when the user lifted their finger. After that calculate the angle of the points and use that to move. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
 -(void) dragging:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)p{
    UIView *v = p.view;
    CGPoint velocity;
    if(p.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
        self.origC = v.center;
        self.pointIn = [p locationInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
        //NSLog(@"%f",self.pointIn.x);
        //pointInWindow = CGPointMake(pointIn.x, pointIn.y);
    }
    //NSLog(@"%f,%f orig %f, %f",pointInWindow.x, pointInWindow.y,self.origC.x,self.origC.y);
    //velocity = [p velocityInView:v.superview];
    //NSLog(@"x=%f",velocity.x);
    //NSLog(@"y=%f",velocity.y);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        CGPoint delta = [p translationInView:v.superview];
        CGPoint c = self.origC;
        c.x += delta.x;
        c.y += delta.y;
        v.center = c;
    }completion:nil];
    if(p.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
        CGPoint lastPoint = [p locationInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
        NSLog(@"orig %f , last %f",self.pointIn.x,lastPoint.x);
        self.lateC = v.center;
        CGFloat deltaX = self.pointIn.x - lastPoint.x;
        CGFloat deltaY = self.pointIn.y - lastPoint.y;
        double angle = atan(deltaX/deltaY) * 180/M_PI;
        if(angle < 0)
            angle += 360;
        //NSLog(@"%f",angle);
        self.addy = angle;
        self.addx = angle;
    }
}
```

This is in my ViewController :

```
-(void) animateBalls:(NSTimer*) time{
    for(Ball *balls in self.view.subviews){
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        //[UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:NO];
        CGFloat x;
        CGFloat y;
        for(Ball *subBalls in self.view.subviews){
            if(balls != subBalls)
                if((CGRectIntersectsRect([balls frame], [subBalls frame]))){
                    [subBalls changeDirectionX];
                    [subBalls changeDirectionY];
                }

        }
        CGPoint point = balls.center;
        if(point.x + 25 > self.view.bounds.size.width)
            [balls changeDirectionX];
        if(point.x - 25 < 0)
            [balls changeDirectionX];
        if(point.y + 25 > self.view.bounds.size.height)
            [balls changeDirectionY];
        if(point.y - 25 < 0)
            [balls changeDirectionY];
        if(balls.directionX == 1){
            x = point.x + (2 * cos(balls.addx));
        }
        else{
            x = point.x - (2 * cos(balls.addx));
            //balls.addx;
        }
        if(balls.directionY == 1){
            y = point.y + (2 * sin(balls.addx));
        }
        else
            y = point.y - (2 * sin(balls.addx));
        //balls.addy;
        //CGFloat x = (CGFloat) random()/(CGFloat) RAND_MAX * self.view.bounds.size.width;
        //CGFloat y = (CGFloat) random()/(CGFloat) RAND_MAX * self.view.bounds.size.height;

        CGPoint squarePostion = CGPointMake(x, y);
        balls.center = squarePostion;

        [UIView commitAnimations];
        //[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}
```

Comment: How have you debugged?  Can you post some NSLog output?